# Is there a function in Jetpack Compose similar to the 'ZStack' grouping in SwiftUI

Tags: kotlin, swiftui, android-jetpack-compose

I was building a calendar app in SwiftUI and decided to move it to the Jetpack Compose to have a version for Android as well. For the SwiftUI version, I was using a ZStack group to overlay the event cards on the time headings. Is there any way to overlay two `div`s in Kotlin like in SwiftUI?

Comment: Check out [Compose for SwiftUI Developers](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/compose_for/swiftui_devs/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you can use a `Box` and set the z-Index using `zIndex` modifier.

```
Box {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .background(Color.Red)
            .zIndex(1f)
    )
    Box(
        Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .background(Color.Green)
            .zIndex(2f)
    )
    Box(
        Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .zIndex(3f)
    )
}
```

The highest `zIndex` will be in front of the others. If you don't define a zIndex, the last one will be closest one.

Comment: **zIndex** doesn't have to be used only with Box, it's available in all Scopes. See the docs here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers-list#Drawing